# Rails i18n specific error validation formats

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord, internationalization

So you can change an error message in en.yml with something like the following:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        foo:
          attributes:
            amount:
              greater_than_or_equal_to: "Custom GTOE error message."
```

However, this will say the following:

```
Amount Custom GTOE error message.
```

I know I can remove it globally with:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      format: "%{message}"
```

But can I remove the `%{attribute}` for only this validation?

Thanks!

Comment: see https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/7369, still opened though

Comment: Updated to: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/14260

Comment: Documentation says "All of them accept the :on and :message options, which define when the validation should be run and what message should be added to the errors collection if it fails, respectively."

So I think you should use `message: I18n.t('custom.error_message')` in validation parameters. But it's just a random guess, I never used this way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can remove it from the en.yml, but you could make a custom one that I think would have the signature you want:

```
def discount_cannot_be_greater_than_total_value
    if attribute > total_value
      errors.add(:base, "can't be greater than total value")
    end
end
```

Answer (score -5):

```
 validates :amount, :numericality => { :greater_than_or_equal_to => YOUR_VALUE, :message => YOUR_ERROR_MESSAGE }
```

Comment: Incorrect! Still would have "%{attribute} YOUR_ERROR_MESSAGE"

Comment: not correct, as andrew said it will still having attribute